# Android studio: Change the color of the currently active item in the navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I want to change the color of the item in my navigation drawer which is currently enabled. I want that on my Home Activity, the item (Home) in the navigation drawer is colored blue, the oder 2 items (settings, about) rest black... How can I manage to do that?

Answer (score 1):

used below the drawer for changing selection & back color.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_selected_item"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
    app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/drawer_item"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer">
```

put below code in drawable resource.
drawer_selected_item.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

put below file in color resource. drawer_item.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:color="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

to change the color use this app:itemIconTint="@android:color/blue" you can change the blue to any color you want.

Comment: Thank you so much!